# Changing Alpha value of image in Unity3D to create glowing effect

Tags: image, user-interface, animation, unity-game-engine

I have two images: one with a glowing border and one without. I want to create the effect of an image glowing by fading the glowing image in and out. My code:

```
private Image lightImage;
private float alpha;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{

lightImage = GetComponent<Image>();
alpha = Time.deltaTime * 10;

}

void FixedUpdate()
{

// fade to transparent over 500ms.
lightImage.CrossFadeAlpha(0.0f, alpha, false);
// and back over 500ms.
lightImage.CrossFadeAlpha(1.0f, alpha, false);
}
```

I cannot seem to get it to work like I want (a slow transition over time.) It blinks in and out quickly but that is not the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Replace:** `alpha = Time.deltaTime * 10;` **with** `alpha = 0.5f;` And I 
   think you should rename `alpha` variable to `duration`.
2. You do not need to put `CrossFadeAlpha` in a `FixedUpdate()`. It is
   a tween. It does not need to be executed across multiple frames.
   Just put it in `Start()`.
3. Setting `alpha` to absolute 0 is not a good idea because sometimes,
   Unity treats 0 alpha objects as if they were disabled but I'm not
   sure. If you do run into this problem, set the alpha to a value very
   closed to 0 instead (`0.004f` for example).
4. If you want it to fade out **and then** fade in, you should do it
   like this:

   ```
   IEnumerator Fade() { 
       // fade to transparent over 500ms.
       lightImage.CrossFadeAlpha(0.004f, 0.5f, false);

       // Wait for 500ms
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f); 

       // and back over 500ms.
       lightImage.CrossFadeAlpha(1.0f, 0.5f, false);
   }

   void Start() {
       StartCoroutine(Fade());
   }
   ```